# React Native deport Navigator.NavigationBar to an other file (clean code)

Tags: react-native

I have a complex app, with lots of lines so i want to split files at maximum to avoid files of thouthands of lines.

Here is my code :

```
export default class Nav extends Component {
 return(
   <Navigator
     initialRoute={ ... }
     renderScene={ ... }
     navigationBar={ <Navigator.NavigationBar routeMapper={ ... }/> }
   />
 )
}
```

Here is what i want to achieve :

```
export default class Nav extends Component {
 return(
   <Navigator
     initialRoute={ ... }
     renderScene={ ... }
     navigationBar={ <MyNavigationBar/> }
   />
 )
}

export default class MyNavigationBar extends Component {
 return(
   <Navigator.NavigationBar routeMapper={ ... }/>
 )
}
```

But when i do this i have an exception :
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navState.routeStack')

Why is that ? How should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `NavigationBar` component is now missing some properties.

You should try to pass all properties to the `NavigationBar` component.

As mentioned in their [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html)

> This component will receive two props: navigator and navState representing the navigator component and its state. The component is re-rendered when the route changes.

Try this:

```
export default class MyNavigationBar extends Component {
  return(
    <Navigator.NavigationBar {...this.props} routeMapper={ ... }/>
  )
}
```

Comment: I think you found the solution but i'm still new to react native and i don't manage to get it right yet. Could you edit Nav and MyNavigationBar and develop a bit more please ?

Comment: Did my upper answer work?
The problem here is, that `navigationBar` from `Navigator` is passing down 2 properties, which are required for the `Navigator.NavigationBar` component.
Your `MyNavigationBar` will now receive these props. To make the `NavigationBar` work, you can pass all params to it.
`...this.props` will do the same as `navigator={this.props.navigator} navState={this.props.navState}`

Comment: It works, Your answer works as is ! I didn't know the `{...this.props}` syntax so i didn't try it in the first place... Thank you, works great and i think i get why ;)